# PHP parsing JSON Data - No content

Tags: php, arrays, json

I can´t figure out what is wrong with my code, I have a JSON which is structured this way

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "B00PM7UJMA":[
            {
               "Verkaufer":"Je Sens le Bonheur",
               "Stock":71.0,
               "Stock: Sold":7.0,
               "Stock: Sold 30 Days":7.0,
               "FBA":"no"
            },
            {
               "Verkaufer":"Parfumea",
               "Stock":2.0,
               "Stock: Sold":"NaN",
               "Stock: Sold 30 Days":"NaN",
               "FBA":"no"
            }
         ],
         "Insgesamt":[
            73.0
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I am trying to access the "Data" but it won´t work at all. I can´t figure out what the problem is, maybe there is something going on with my JSON?

This is my PHP

```
    $str = file_get_contents($row["URL"]);
    $json = json_encode($str); // decode the JSON into an associative array
    $jsondecode = json_decode($json, true);

    print_r($jsondecode['data']); // doesn´t work at all
    print_r($jsondecode->data); // doesn´t work either
```

Does someone know what the problem could be? I worked a lot with JSON via PHP. I bet the solution is really easy, but I just need someone others opinion on this one.

Thank you

Comment: `$json = json_encode($str); // decode the JSON into an associative array` It isn't decoding bro. You are basically double encoding the string.

Comment: You are encoding before decoding, which doesn't make sense. Just drop `$json = json_encode($str);`, your string is already JSON.

Comment: @nice_dev  I tried as well, thank you, but somehow it just turns out in a blank response when I try it this way

Comment: @derd1199 Closing as your issue is not reproducible. See http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/29249c1ec7b78bb9dd2f2c754b994412a40e71a4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I arranged your code a bit.
You are encoding first and after that decoding again. I think it is redundant.

If you give `$str` directly to decode, it will work.

```
$jsondecode = json_decode($str);
print_r($jsondecode->data);
```

Also if you want to take the output as an array, you should add `true` to `json_decode` and print with square brackets like that

```
$jsondecode = json_decode($str, true);
print_r($jsondecode['data']);
```

Comment: I tried it as well, somehow it just gives me a blank response

Comment: Thank you @Gunobaba I tried to add the boolean true and access the data with square brackets but it somehow still just return an empty response

Comment: Then I think json may not be taken clearly from the URL. because I tried with assigning the above json code to $str variable and give it to decode function.

Comment: When I print the whole json print_r($jsondecode) it will return the full json. As soon as I am trying to parse it by accessing 'data' it will return a blank one. I am getting the same json from a .json link I store on my server. Idk what is going on here

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = '{"data":[{"B00PM7UJMA":[{"Verkaufer":"Je Sens le Bonheur","Stock":71.0,"Stock: Sold":7.0,"Stock: Sold 30 Days":7.0,"FBA":"no"},{"Verkaufer":"Parfumea","Stock":2.0,"Stock: Sold":"NaN","Stock: Sold 30 Days":"NaN","FBA":"no"}],"Insgesamt":[73.0]}]}';

$json = json_decode($str, false);

print_r($json->data);
print_r($json->data[0]);
print_r($json->data[0]->B00PM7UJMA);
print_r($json->data[0]->B00PM7UJMA[0]);
print_r($json->data[0]->B00PM7UJMA[0]->Verkaufer);
```

The final line prints: "Je Sens le Bonheur"